# How to handle django application having multiple databases in celery

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

I am using multiple databases in my django application and the database is selected on the basis of url. All the views are working properly and use the database as required. Now, I have an API which exports the data into excel and I am trying to shift main logic of this API to a background tasks using celery. The issue I am facing is that celery is using default database for querying which is not required. So how can I make celery use database based on url.

I am using python 3.7, django 2.2.11, django rest framework 3.11.0, celery 4.4.3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you just send the database to be used through a parameter to the tasks?

Comment: I thought of doing that and use the manual selection of database through "using" method. But there are lot of queries and there is a generalized logic for creating these queries which is also used in different views. So I don't want to touch that logic, is there any other way to do this?